# Can Wear / Tear destroy a Chalice of the Void with X=1?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens with Wear / Tear when there's a Chalice of the Void with X=1? Does the Chalice recognize the Wear as having a casting cost of 2 or does it somehow see the Tear and a casting cost of 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Wear // Tear will not be countered

As per [the rules on Split cards](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Split_card):

> 708.4. In every zone except the stack, the characteristics of a split card are those of its two halves combined. This is a change from previous rules.
>
> 708.3a Only the chosen half is evaluated to see if it can be cast. Only that half is considered to be put onto the stack.
>
> 708.3b While on the stack, only the characteristics of the half being cast exist. The other half’s characteristics are treated as though they didn’t exist.

Your fuse card will either have the CMC of three in all zones except the stack, it can also have a CMC of one or two depending on which part of the split card you use or also a CMC of three on the stack if you fuse it.

It could very easily be countered if you try and destroy an enchantment with it but that is not part of your question.